# WebRTC change microphone or webcam while in call

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am trying to figure out how to change the microphone or webcam **while** you are in a videochat with someone.

---

I have been now trying for a few days and nothing works.
I was following [this example](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/), but it seems it is much harder to achieve the change while someone is already connected.

The issues I have: If I change the mic the sound is lost/the mic doesnt react at all. I also cannot change it back to the default.

A similar thing happens if I change the webcam. The stream hangs, the last frame is seen.

I get no error message, in fact it tells me that the changes were successful.

**Changing the webcam/mic WORKS before the call is established**

---

Here is the relevant codeblock. Everywhere I am reading just create new constraints and give the desired deviceId to the audio/video stream.:

```
function ChangeDevice() {

  if (localStream) {
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      track.stop();
    });
  }

  var audioSource = audioInputSelect.value;
  var videoSource = videoSelect.value;

  console.log(videoSource);
  console.log(audioSource);

  const newConstraints = {
    audio: {deviceId: audioSource ? {exact: audioSource} : undefined},
    video: {deviceId: videoSource ? {exact: videoSource} : undefined}
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(newConstraints).then(gotStream).then(gotDevices).catch(handleError);
}

function gotStream(stream) {

  console.log('Adding local stream.');
  localStream = stream;
  localVideo.srcObject = stream;
  sendMessage(['got user media', room]);
  if (isInitiator) {
    maybeStart();
  }
  return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices(); // I added this

}
```

I think these two are the relevant functions, ChangeDevice is called when I select a new device from a dropdown. The id's are correct.

Here is the whole code I use:

[pastebin.com/6JrK4jJD](https://pastebin.com/6JrK4jJD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily `replaceTrack` seems to work now on all browsers, so there is no need to renegotiate.

I had to edit my `gotStream` function like this:

```
function gotStream(stream) {

  // If already started
  // Need this if webcam or mic changes
  if (isStarted) {
    var videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    var audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];

    var sender = pc.getSenders().find(function(s) {
      return s.track.kind == videoTrack.kind;
    });

    var sender2 = pc.getSenders().find(function(s) {
      return s.track.kind == audioTrack.kind;
    });

    console.log('found sender:', sender);
    sender.replaceTrack(videoTrack);
    sender2.replaceTrack(audioTrack);

    localStream = stream;
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;

  } else {
    console.log('Adding local stream.');
    localStream = stream;
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    sendMessage(['got user media', room]);
    if (isInitiator) {
      maybeStart();
    }
  }

  return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices(); // I added this

}
```